# How would you store a value produced in a for loop after each iteration in c?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

If I had a for loop that looks like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++){

    printf("you entered %d", number);
    //store number in int arr[][]

}
```

Would the resulting arr need to be initialized in that for loop? Or can I access arr after the for loop finishes?

Comment: Where have you defined `int arr[][]`?

Comment: Why would `arr` be two-dimensional?

Comment: If it is defined outside of the loop then yes you can use it outside of the loop

Comment: so it needs to be initialized before the for loop.

Comment: @davidobravo ah yes sorry from the wording of your question I didn't realize that was in fact what you were asking

Comment: Yeah, to access it outside of the loop you have to define it outside of the loop. Although, you don't have to _initialize_ it outside of the loop, just define it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the array outside of the loop, define it outside the loop:

```
int arr[size][size]; // or whatever number you want to use here
for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
    printf("you entered %d", number);
    //store number in int arr[][]
}

// access values of arr here
```

You don't need to *initialize* the array outside of the loop (fill it with some values) if you're just planning on overwriting those values with the values produced in the array.